# How to get the filenames of all categories (TP, TN, FP, FN) of a Confusion Matrix in Keras/TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, confusion-matrix

I am working with image data where I am trying to find the list of the files are in `TP, TN (true positives, true negatives)` and so on. The purpose is to check (visually) whether the files are being identified properly by the model. currntly I am using a sequential image classification model in google colab. Following is my code.

```
## Model
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(128, 128, 1)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, shear_range=0.2, zoom_range=0.2, horizontal_flip=True)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('./train', target_size=(128, 128), batch_size=batch_size, color_mode = 'grayscale', class_mode='binary')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('./validation', target_size=(128, 128), batch_size=batch_size, color_mode = 'grayscale', class_mode='binary')

test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('./test', target_size=(128, 128), batch_size=1,
        color_mode = 'grayscale', class_mode='binary', shuffle=False)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

h = model.fit(train_generator, epochs = 50, validation_data=validation_generator)

from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
y_true = test_generator.classes
true_classes = test_generator.classes
class_labels = list(test_generator.class_indices.keys())
confusion_matrix(y_true, yy_pred)
```

Output of confusion Matrix-

```
array([[22, 10],
       [9, 50]])
```

Where I am trying to get image file names those are in True Positives (22 images), True Negatives (50 images) and so on. I am not sure whether I can get a list directly or do I have to re-generate the predicted images!

Comment: You cannot get such stuff from the confusion matrix, which is just a *summary* of the results.

Comment: You can only skip on `test_generator`, loop through each file in the test folder, and segregate them based on the classification result with some custom script

Comment: @VishalBalaji would you please explain a bit more on the steps of segregating the images based on classification result?

Answer (score 0):

The function below will processes the test_generator and produce a classification report and a confusion matrix as well as a list of filenams the were misclassified.
You can process the classification report to get the metrics you desire

```
def predictor(test_gen):    
    y_pred= []
    error_list=[]
    error_pred_list = []
    y_true=test_gen.labels
    classes=list(test_gen.class_indices.keys())
    class_count=len(classes)
    errors=0
    preds=model.predict(test_gen, verbose=1)
    tests=len(preds)    
    for i, p in enumerate(preds):        
        pred_index=np.argmax(p)         
        true_index=test_gen.labels[i]  # labels are integer values        
        if pred_index != true_index: # a misclassification has occurred                                           
            errors=errors + 1
            file=test_gen.filenames[i]
            error_list.append(file)
            error_class=classes[pred_index]
            error_pred_list.append(error_class)
        y_pred.append(pred_index)
            
    acc=( 1-errors/tests) * 100
    msg=f'there were {errors} errors in {tests} tests for an accuracy of {acc:6.2f}'
    print_in_color(msg, (0,255,255), (100,100,100)) # cyan foreground
    ypred=np.array(y_pred)
    ytrue=np.array(y_true)
    f1score=f1_score(ytrue, ypred, average='weighted')* 100
    if class_count <=30:
        cm = confusion_matrix(ytrue, ypred )
        # plot the confusion matrix
        plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
        sns.heatmap(cm, annot=True, vmin=0, fmt='g', cmap='Blues', cbar=False)       
        plt.xticks(np.arange(class_count)+.5, classes, rotation=90)
        plt.yticks(np.arange(class_count)+.5, classes, rotation=0)
        plt.xlabel("Predicted")
        plt.ylabel("Actual")
        plt.title("Confusion Matrix")
        plt.show()
    clr = classification_report(y_true, y_pred, target_names=classes, digits= 4) # create classification report
    print("Classification Report:\n----------------------\n", clr)
    return errors, tests, error_list, error_pred_list, f1score

errors, tests, error_list, error_pred_list, f1score =predictor(test_gen)
```